# ORA-30372 fine grain access policy conflicts with materialized view

Tags: sql, oracle, replication, materialized

I'm trying to create Materialized view which will run every 6 hour at DB1, and replicate data from DB2 table.
I have created MLOG$_REMOTE_TABLE1 on DB2 remote table.

I'm using Oracle 11g (p.s oracle 12g has no problem while executing this script )

While executing this script below , I'm getting Error:

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW REPL_TABLE1
REFRESH FORCE ON DEMAND
START WITH SYSDATE NEXT SYSDATE + 6/24
ENABLE QUERY REWRITE
AS
SELECT * FROM REMOTE_TABLE1_SYN;
```

> ORA-30372: fine grain access policy conflicts with materialized view

Could you please, let me know why I have this Problem on 11g and not on the 12g (is it a bug of 11g)?
And how can I solve it?

Comment: ORA-30372 is thrown even when mview logs are not in place, having complete refreshes over DB link from a VPD-affected table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a Solution By using

```
REFRESH FORCE ON DEMAND WITH ROWID USING TRUSTED CONSTRAINTS
```

In my case I have table with aprox. 100 record, it's a small table so I can use ROWID. 
But using ROWID on a Big table is not good idea, because it will search the row in whole table, and replication of table will take too long time.

Comment: Although basically a workaround, not a solution to the problem we have, it helped us relieve our pain from local (miserable) corporate VPD implementation.

Answer (score 4):

All you need is:
REFRESH FORCE ON DEMAND **USING TRUSTED CONSTRAINTS**.

That way your query can ignore restrictions imposed by Oracle VPD.